# Throw spheres randomly from a fixed point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create new spheres on each update run, and I want all of them to start from a fixed point and to be thrown outwards to a random direction, including all x,y,z

How do I go on about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To create a prefab for the sphere and inside it you place a script called spheremovement. Inside this script you can use a random.range to the RB.AddForce at the start. When this is added on the script were you launch these spheres you can Instantiate them from the prefab with Instantiate(spheregameobject, transorm.position, quaternion.identity). You could also randomize the last quaternion if you want more randomness